# How to change the href of this SVG sprite using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using an SVG sprite sheet and I am trying to change the href of the svg using vanilla javascript, but after researching a solution, have run into a brick wall.

html

```js
let scores, roundScore, activePlayer, dice, diceSvg, diceImg, diceHrefString;

scores = [0,0];
roundScore = 0;
activePlayer = 0;

document.querySelector(`#p${activePlayer}c-score`).textContent = dice;
diceSvg = document.getElementById("dice-icon");
diceSvg.style.display = "none";

document.getElementById("roll-dice").addEventListener("click",function(){
 dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
 diceImg = document.querySelector(".dice-icon");
    diceHrefString = `dice_sprite_sheet.svg#dice-${dice}`;
    if(dice !== 0){
        diceImg.setAttributeNS("xlink:","href",diceHrefString);
    }else{
     diceImg.setAttributeNS("xlink:","href","dice");
    }
        diceSvg.style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<svg class="dice-icon" id="dice-icon">
    <use xlink:href="dice_sprite_sheet.svg#dice"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: `xlink:` -> `xlink` - in other words, `:` is not part of a namespace, usually

Comment: @JaromandaX - actually it is OK (although deprecated). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#Attributes

Comment: deprecated is never ok and probably has unusual side effects :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - agreed - but, as you can see in my answer, that isn't the issue.

Comment: Please use: `const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";diceImg.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#dice');` where `#dice` is the id of the used element

Comment: Where's the element `<use>` is copying? It might be easier to change the original depending on what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've commented: you need to use the svg xlink namespace: `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`. When you change the value of the `xlink:href` dynamically this is how you do it: `theUse.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#theId');`

This is an example:

```js
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
theUse.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#spade');
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg class="dice-icon" id="dice-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="200" height="200">
    <use id="theUse" xlink:href="#heart"></use>
</svg>


<svg width="0" height="0" display="none">
<title>symbols defs</title>
<defs>
<symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="spade" style="overflow: visible">
<title>Spade</title>
<path d="M9,15C9,20 0,21 0,16S6,9 10,0C14,9 20,11 20,16 S11,20 11,15Q11,20 13,20H7Q9,20 9,15Z"/>
</symbol>

<symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="heart" style="overflow: visible">
<title>heart</title>
<path d="M10,6 Q10,0 15,0T20,6Q20,10 15,14 T10,20Q10,18 5,14T0,6Q0,0 5,0T10,6Z"/>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: THank you to everyone that pitched in, your help is appreciated.